# Or condition in Sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I'm checking two sed conditions, trying to add in a single sed command, but it doesn't work.

Input:

```
"Southern/Palms"|"AA|None"|"4"|"Ken|Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|
```

Expected Output:

```
"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Ken Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|
```

Trying to remove delimiter (`|` or `\`) from double quoted fields.

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^"|])\|($|[^"|]) | (^|[^"|])\\($|[^"|]) /\1 \2/g'
```

I tried also the following way with delimiter `|` or  `\` condition:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^"|])\|\\($|[^"|])/\1 \2/g'
```

Comment: @Jotne I have added sample data in question

Comment: Why does your expected output include `"Ken|Coast"` and not `"Ken Coast"`?

Comment: And you say you're trying to remove backslashes but in your sample data you seem to be removing `/` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)gsub(/[/|]/," ",$i)}7' file
```

#### Note: this solution assumes all your quotes are paired.

Test with my gawk:

```
kent$  cat f
"Southern/Palms"|"AA|None"|"4"|"Ken|Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|

kent$  awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)gsub(/[/|]/," ",$i)}7' f
"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Ken Coast"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"|
```